# What does the "@" (at) symbol mean on OSX ls?

Tags: permissions, osx, ls

When I check permission of less files from the command line on my Snow Leopard OSX system using Bash I see `-rw-r--r--@`
for certain files and for others I just see `-rw-r--r--` What does the @ mean here?

Answer (score 166, accepted):

On OSX, the `@` symbol indicates that the file has [extended attributes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_file_attributes#macOS). You can see them using `xattr -l`, or `ls -l@`. From `man 1 ls` on OSX 10.9:

```
The following options are available:
-@      Display extended attribute keys and sizes in long (-l) output.
...
If the file or directory has extended attributes, 
the permissions field printed by the `-l` option is followed by a `@` character.
```

Comment: Thanks! I just tried and I saw 
    xattr -l variables.less 
    com.macromates.caret:
    ..
Need to see why TextMate does this..

Comment: And just in case if you want to remove those attribes, you can use `xattr -c filename.ext` or `xattr -cr somefolder` to do it recursively.